# executing a script within chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, electron

```
<div id="Monitor2" class="tabcontent">
        <h1 class="lable2">Monitor 2</h1>
        <button id="open1" onclick="open2()" class="open2">Open</button>
        <h1 class="server2">server</h1>
        <input type="text" id="server2" class="input-server2">
        <h1 class="channel2" >channel</h1>
        <input type="text" id="channel2" class="input-channel2">
            <script>

function open2() {
    var main= 'https://discord.com/channels/' ;
    var server= document.getElementById("server2").value;
    var slash= '/';
    var channel= document.getElementById("channel2").value;
        var newurl=main+server+slash+channel;

            window.open(newurl,'monitor2','width=600, height=1000');

}
contents.executeJavaScript(
document.querySelector(".sidebar-2K8pFh").style.display = "none"
        );
            </script>
    </div>
```

My script opens an electron window with discord but idk how to do actions within the window. I tried by using "contents.execute.JavaScript" but its not working.
the string that im trying to have run within the window works when i paste it directly into the DevTools chrome console and run but idk how to have it do those things alone within electron